# How to create Hidden type Field in Drupal 8 Entity

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am using drupal 8, I have an Entity, I want to add a hidden type field in Entity Form. How I can add hidden field type? like below

```
<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='my_hidden' />
</form>
```

Code Generating Form is as below:

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) 
{
   $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Timeslot entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two steps to make a field hidden in drupal 8 entity forms.

1. If you want to make an existing field hidden you may alter the form and update that field as

   $form['your_field_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'hidden';
2. You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/field_hidden and by enabling this module, Select the 'Hidden field' widget for a field in the entity type's 'Manage form display' dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

If you work only with the UI, you can disabled the display of a field in the "Manage form display". But I assume that you ask for your own coded Form... It's like that :

```
$form['my_hidden'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $my_hidden_value, 
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Arioch, I am sorry I forget to mention the drupal version, I am using drupal 8. I also updated my question.

Comment: I only work with Drupal8. Can you show the code who generates your Form ?

Comment: So you have to do the 1st solution given by Satyam Bhardwaz. But that means you will be using a hook_form_alter like this : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.3.x

Comment: There is no need to alter hook, code work for me is:
`$form['price'] = array(
     '#type' => 'hidden',
     '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'price',
     ),
     '#default_value' => $session_price,
    );`

Comment: Ok so it's "#default_value" and not "#value" like I though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) 
{
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
        ->setLabel(t('ID'))
        ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Timeslot entity.'))
        ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
        ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'weight' => -5,
        );
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it hide the field from form or doesn't create field in form.

Comment: It should just hide the field cause you tells that you want this field as "type=hidden" when you display a "form".
You tried it and it doesn't create the field at all ?

Comment: Arioch, thank you for your help and time. Yes, It doesn't create field at all, I think hidden means not to render field in form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the field to be hidden just like you define any other field and then in the buildForm method for the entity form set the following

```
$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'hidden';
```

That will make the field to become a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Add `'#access' => FALSE,` into the form element array.